# Core Data not loading without a value for optional relationship attribute?!? Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

I'm new to **Core Data**, and while it is slowly making sense, I've a problem loading my initial *database* when I leave 'optional' *relationship* values without values (isn't that what optionals do?). The following code WORKS, but not if I leave out some cases that instantiate and define a relationship (exact detail below).

I'm using a class to load the data via a for loop that assigns the initialising values and passes them to a method that effectively loads the data. Firstly, to load an Entity called Gender.

```
class LoadData
{
init ()
{
    for count in 0...3
    {
        var text = "Value not found"
        let sortOrder: Int32 = Int32(count)

        switch count
        {
        case 0:
            text = "Masculine"
        case 1:
            text = "Neutral"
        case 2:
            text = "Feminine"
        case 3:
            text = "Plural"
        default:
            text = "Value unassigned"
        }
        loadGender(text: text, sortOrder: sortOrder)
    }
```

In the same class and init, a separate for loop defines values and passes to save the context in the *Entity, CellData*. For CellData entries defined in *cases 0 to 27 and 28 to 51*, I use a predicate to instantiate a specific Gender entry...

```
    for count in 0...51
    {
        var text = "Cell text not found"
        ...
        var dataToGender: Gender? = nil


        switch count
        {
        case 0...27:     // HERE - if case 1...27, data will NOT load

            guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
                else { return }
            let moc = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let request = NSFetchRequest<Gender>(entityName: "Gender")

            let genderToFetch = "Masculine"
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "text == %@", genderToFetch)

            do
            {
                let fetched = try moc.fetch(request)
                dataToGender = fetched[0] as Gender
            } catch
            { fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)") }

        case 28...51:
            guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
                else { return }     // get the app delegate
            let moc = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let request = NSFetchRequest<Gender>(entityName: "Gender")

            let genderToFetch = "Feminine"
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "text == %@", genderToFetch)

            do
            {
                let fetched = try moc.fetch(request)
                dataToGender = fetched[0] as Gender
            } catch
            { fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)") }

        default: return
        }

        ...
```

... which is passed into the method to put the data into the context and saved to Core Data.

```
func loadCellData(text: String, sortOrder: Int32, portion: Float, color1: String?, color2: String?, color3: String?, colorRangeLoc1: Int32?, colorRangeLoc2: Int32?, colorRangeLoc3: Int32?, colorRangeLen1: Int32?, colorRangeLen2: Int32?, colorRangeLen3: Int32?, underlineRangeLoc1: Int32?, underlineRangeLoc2: Int32?, underlineRangeLoc3: Int32?, underlineRangeLen1: Int32?, underlineRangeLen2: Int32?, underlineRangeLen3: Int32?, dataToGender: NSObject?)
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entry: CellData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "CellData", into: context) as! CellData
    ...
    entry.text = text
    ...
    entry.dataToGender = dataToGender as? Gender

    do { try context.save() ; print("saved")}
    catch let error as NSError
    { print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)") }
}
```

Amazingly, this works fine - but only if I define a relationship for all CellData entries. However, I do not want all entries to have a relationship (see comment // HERE). Cases 0...7 should not have a relationship, but if no value is assigned, the code executes fine - until calling on a DB value. On inspection, Gender enters fine, but no CellData entries were entered into the DB, so it crashes with no object found at index 0 section 0.

There are no errors in log; and I can print inside the loadCellData!?! What is going on?!?

Comment: Basically it's very expensive to fetch records from Core Data one by one. Most likely you can load all records with one fetch and appropriate predicate and sort descriptor What is the code supposed to do at all?

Comment: The code / relationship is supposed to make it possible to sort and manage contents for a collection view. At UI, the user picks a Gender value, and I hope to be able to fetch CellData with a relationship to the Gender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, an optional value in CoreData is not the same as a Swift optional value. Integers should never be optional, and maybe relationships also. To get around this, for integers at least, an impossible value should be assigned instead of nil, and used to check if a value is assigned.

While I understand it is expensive, I did not find a way to assign a relationship to an existing record in CoreData without fetching the record individually.